# How do I remove duplicates where one has a null value in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

**Problem**

Sorry to all who have helped, but I have had to rephrase the question. I have a dataframe with duplicates for most of the columns, except the last column. Where I have duplicates, I want to apply the following rule:

1. If both have valid entries in the last column, then keep both.
2. If both have null entries in the last column, then keep one.
3. If one has a valid entry and the other a null entry, then keep the valid entry.

I then want to take the duplicate values out and create a separate dataframe with them. At the moment, my approach is laborious and deletes both duplicates where they are both null.

**Reprex**

***Starting Dataframe***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_input = {'Student':     ['A', 'A',          'B', 'B',            'C',      'D',      'E',      'F', 'F',         'G',     "H",     "H", "I", "I"], 
              "Subject": ["Law", "Law",      "Maths", "Maths",    "Maths", "Law",    "Maths",  "Music", "Music", "Music",      "Art", "Art", "Dance", "Dance"], 
              "Checked":  ["Bob", "James",    np.nan,  "Jack",     "Laura", "Laura",  np.nan,    np.nan, "Tim",   "Tim",       "Tim", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

# Create DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_input)
```

[image]

***Desired Output***

[image]

***First Attempt***

```
attempt1 = df1.sort_values(['Student', 'Checked'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(["Student", "Subject"]).sort_index()
```

I took this from another Q&A on Stack, but it does not give me the outcome I want and I don't understand it.

***Attempt 2***

```
#Create Duplicate column
df1["Duplicates"] = df1.duplicated(subset=["Student", "Subject"], keep=False)

#Create list of rows with no duplicates
df_new1 = df1[df1["Duplicates"]==False]

#Create list of rows with duplicates & remove all those with null values
#HERE IS WHERE I GET STUCK. IF BOTH DUPLICATES ARE NULLS, I WANT TO KEEP ONE OF THEM
df_new2 = df1[df1["Duplicates"]==True]
df_new3 = df_new2[~df_new2["Checked"].isnull()]

#Combine unique rows, and duplicates without null values
#Keep duplicates without null values
df_new = df_new1.append(df_new3)

#Tidy up
df_new = df_new[["Student", "Subject", "Checked"]].sort_values(by="Student")

df_new
```

***I can then create a list of the duplicates that both appear valid***

```
#Create separate list of duplicates with valid "Checked" values
df_new["Duplicates"] = df_new.duplicated(subset="Student", keep=False)
conflicting_duplicates = df_new[df_new["Duplicates"]==True]
conflicting_duplicates
```

***Help***

Thank you to everyone! Your answers helped, but I hadn't realised that I also want to keep one of the entries where both are null.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean indexing:

```
# is the group containing more than one row?
m1 = df1.duplicated(['Student', 'Subject'], keep=False)
# is the row a NaN in "Checked"?
m2 = df1['Checked'].isna()
# both conditions True
m = m1&m2

# keep if either condition is False 
df1[~m]

# to get dropped duplicates
# keep if both are True
df1[m]
```

Output:

```
   Student Subject Checked
0        A     Law     Bob
1        A     Law   James
3        B   Maths    Jack
4        C   Maths   Laura
5        D     Law   Laura
6        E   Maths     NaN
8        F   Music     Tim
9        G   Music     Tim
10       H     Art     Tim
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This answered my original questions and also helped me answer the one I added later i.e. remove the duplicates where both have null in the "Checked" column. I used your method but added the following line to answer the extra question: 

                                                                                                                               m0 = df1.duplicated(["Student", "Subject", "Checked"],keep="first");                                          

df_final = pd.concat([df1[~m], df1[m0]])

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new helper column using `np.where` which will flag the rows that satisfy the conditions you specified.  If I understand you correctly you want to keep the rows that are duplicated in 'Student' and 'Subject', and also have a `null` value in 'Checked' column.

You can then use `loc` to remove the flagged ones:

```
import numpy as np

df1['to_drop'] = np.where(
    (df1['Student'].isin(df1[df1[['Student','Subject']].duplicated()]['Student'].tolist())
     ) & (df1['Checked'].isnull()),1,0)

df1.loc[df1.to_drop==0].drop('to_drop',axis=1)
```

prints:

```
   Student Subject Checked
0        A     Law     Bob
1        A     Law   James
3        B   Maths    Jack
4        C   Maths   Laura
5        D     Law   Laura
6        E   Maths     NaN
8        F   Music     Tim
9        G   Music     Tim
10       H     Art     Tim
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and drop [`NaN`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) values

```
df.groupby("Student", sort=False).apply(lambda x : x if len(x) == 1 else x.dropna(subset=['Checked'])).reset_index(drop=True)
```

##### Output :

This gives us the expected output

```
  Student Subject Checked
0       A     Law     Bob
1       A     Law   James
2       B   Maths    Jack
3       C   Maths   Laura
4       D     Law   Laura
5       E   Maths     NaN
6       F   Music     Tim
7       G   Music     Tim
8       H     Art     Tim
```

Answer (score 1):

My take using Boolean indexing:

```
s_idx = ~(df1[(df1.duplicated(subset=['Student','Subject'],keep=False))])['Checked'].isna()

idx = [x for x in df1.index.values if x not in s_idx[~s_idx].index]

df1.iloc[idx]
```

Output:

```
   Student Subject Checked
0        A     Law     Bob
1        A     Law   James
3        B   Maths    Jack
4        C   Maths   Laura
5        D     Law   Laura
6        E   Maths     NaN
8        F   Music     Tim
9        G   Music     Tim
10       H     Art     Tim
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.drop_duplicates().groupby(["Student", "Subject"], sort=False).apply(lambda x 
: 
x if len(x) == 1 else x.dropna(subset= 
['Checked'])).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

It's pretty similar to Himanshuman's code but i dropped the duplicates before grouping.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdvhb.png)